# ASP.net Integration Pattern - examples

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns

Recently lot of interviewers are asking

"What are the integration patterns are you familiar with?".

I know design patterns,what is integration pattern then?

Comment: Great question, I would not have known this if asked (though I totally know the patterns, just not the term).  You should tag the question with integration-patterns and not asp.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, its how the apps would integrate, that is - **communicate**, usually in an enterprise environment.

The [integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978729.aspx) could be of any sort ranging from network sockets, to web services, MSMQ, databases, [BDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413930.aspx)s; this includes data integration, functionalities, presentation, etc - among a range of technologies that may include SQL Server, IIS, Biztalk, MOSS, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Integration Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978729.aspx)
[Enterprise Integration Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321200683)